# Devise - overriding ParameterSanitizer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am attempting to configure a different Devise strong parameter sanitizer per model following the instructions at; https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

I have created a new file named parameter_sanitizer within my Employer model directory;

app/controllers/Employers/paramater_sanitizer.rb

```
class Employer::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
  def initialize(*)
    super
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:forename, :surname, :username)
  end
end
```

Within my application controller I have;

```
    require 'employers/parameter_sanitizer'

    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
          before_filter :devise_parameter_sanitizer, if: :devise_controller?
          protect_from_forgery with: :exception

          protected

          def devise_parameter_sanitizer
            if resource_class == Employer
              Employer::ParameterSanitizer.new(Employer, :employer, params)
            else
              super # Use the default one
            end
          end
    end
```

The error I get from signing up an Employer object is;

NameError in Devise::ConfirmationsController#show
undefined local variable or method `devise_parameter_sanitizer' for #

Any advice on how to overcome this?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: app/controllers/Employers/parameter_sanitizer.rb

Comment: class Employers::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this `initialize` method you save the `params` as an instance variables `@params` so in your method you should do:

```
class Employer::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
  def initialize(*)
    super
    @params.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:forename, :surname, :username])
  end
```

also I believe this should work without specifying `@params`

---

### Explanation

to find the solution to this problem check the `devise api` to better understand the methods you are calling and read the [`Devise::ParameterSanitizer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb) source code

I am quoting their ruby-rocs about the [`#permit()` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/ParameterSanitizer#permit-instance_method)

> ## Instance Method Details

```
#permit(action, keys: nil, except: nil, &block) ⇒ Object
```

> Add or remove new parameters to the permitted list of an action.
>
> Arguments
> `action` - A Symbol with the action that the controller is performing, like `sign_up`, `sign_in`, etc.
>
> `keys`: - An Array of keys that also should be permitted.
>
> `except`: - An Array of keys that shouldn't be permitted.
>
> `block` - A block that should be used to permit the action parameters instead of the Array based approach. The block will be called with an `ActionController::Parameters` instance.
>
> Examples

```
# Adding new parameters to be permitted in the `sign_up` action.

devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:subscribe_newsletter])

# Removing the `password` parameter from the `account_update` action.
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, except: [:password])

# Using the block form to completely override how we permit the
# parameters for the `sign_up` action.
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user|
  user.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

> Returns nothing.

Also I quote

> If you have multiple Devise models, you may want to set up a different parameter sanitizer per model. In this case, we recommend inheriting from Devise::ParameterSanitizer and adding your own logic:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protected

  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    if resource_class == User
      User::ParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)
    else
      super # Use the default one
    end
  end
end
```

`User::ParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)` will call this initializer method from [`parameter_sanitizer.rb` source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb)

```
def initialize(resource_class, resource_name, params)
   @auth_keys      = extract_auth_keys(resource_class)
   @params         = params
   @resource_name  = resource_name
   @permitted      = {}

   DEFAULT_PERMITTED_ATTRIBUTES.each_pair do |action, keys|
     permit(action, keys: keys)
   end
end
```

so basically you are calling `initialize(User, :user, params)`, I don't understand why devise is accepting `params` in this method, as it has his own way of allowing attributes by saving a static hash of permitted field.

```
DEFAULT_PERMITTED_ATTRIBUTES = {
   sign_in: [:password, :remember_me],
   sign_up: [:password, :password_confirmation],
   account_update: [:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password]
}
```

and the permitting them with a loop

```
DEFAULT_PERMITTED_ATTRIBUTES.each_pair do |action, keys|
   permit(action, keys: keys)
end
```

In this `initialize` method you save the `params` as an instance variables `@params` so in your method you should do:

```
class Employer::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
  def initialize(*)
    super
    @params.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:forename, :surname, :username])
  end
```